# How to optimize query performance in a many to many table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table and a virtual item table, each with ID values as primary keys.

I also have a favorites table where users can store their favorite items. The favorites table maps user_id to item_id. Many users can favorite many items.

```
table users
user_id  bigint primary key auto_increment
...

table items
item_id  bigint primary key auto_increment
...

table favorites
user_id  bigint 
item_id  bigint
```

Since I cannot create indexes on the favorites table, because there are no unique or primary keys, how do i optimize search queries, such as SELECT? Is there a better way to store the data?

Comment: "I cannot create indexes on the favorites table, because there are no unique or primary keys" Says who???

Comment: You're right! I was operating under misinformation, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Since I cannot create indexes on the favorites table, because there are no unique or primary keys

Huh?  Of course you can create indexes.  In fact, two come to mind:

- `favorites(user_id, item_id)`
- `favorites(item_id, user_id)`

These would be used to answer different questions.  Respective examples are:  What are the favorites of user X?  What users have a favorite of Y?

Comment: I'm not sure where I got the impression that indicies had to be based on primary keys, but that was an implicit assumption that I had that I hadn't even questioned.  This answer is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @mshap . . . Primary keys are implemented *using* an index -- as are unique constraints.  But indexes do not have to be unique.

Comment: The syntax that you used, why are you specifying two columns for the respective queries that you stated they fulfill? If you just specify favorites(user_id), for example, wouldn't that already just point you to every row with a specific user_id, which would satisfy the first query you listed?

Comment: @mshap . . . The second column is convenient so the index is a covering index for any query that uses it.